# How to create a mutli page Vue.js app without Vue-Cli?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I created a Vue.js app without using Vue CLI, so that means I did everything from scratch including setting up Webpack 4. The reason I did this was because I don't like the idea of frameworks concealing the inner workings of things so that I can't fix things myself.

As an SPA, I have got the basic demo site working with an `Home` and `About` view. But I am looking to create a multi-page app with Express. The only information on multi-page Vue.js apps seems to be linked to the `pages` option that only comes with Vue CLI ([see here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-on-multi-page-app-and-page-reload/48405/2))

Is there a way to have a multi-page app for projects created without Vue CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could handle routing with Express and have the page rendered server-side.
You can use Vue official package for routing, vue-router and choose between SSR (server-side rendering) or client side.

I suggest you to check this official doc about it: https://ssr.vuejs.org/

Comment: if I go with SSR, then do I still need vue-router? I don't see how having a `<routerview/>` tag would help when I would like all my pages to be SSR. Could you possibly provide some code example?